# Should I use one class or more?

Tags: oop, heuristics

In my PHP web application, I want to have the ability to perform the following logging operations:

1. Write a database record to an 'error_log' table.
2. Write a database record to a 'history_log' table.
3. Log all queries to the Firebug console via FirePHP.
4. Log any arbitrary data to the Firebug console using FirePHP.

I am trying to decide on the better achitecture. I have two in mind. Which of these is the better one? I'm open to others as well.

### Design #1

- abstract class Logger

  - class FirebugConsoleLogger

    - getInstance()
    - log(string)
  - class DatabaseLogger

    - getInstance()
    - logError(logTypeId, affiliateId, detailsArray)
    - logHistory(logTypeId, affiliateId, detailsArray)

### Design #2

- class Logger
- getInstance()
- logToFirebugConsole(string)
- logError(string)
- logHistory(string)

*EDIT* Here's what I'm probably going to go with.

- class FirebugConsoleLogger

  - public getInstance()
  - public log(string)
- abstract class Logger

  - abstract public log(typeId, affiliateId, details)
  - class ErrorLogger

    - public getInstance()
    - public log(typeId, affiliateId, details)
  - class HistoryLogger

    - public getInstance()
    - public log(typeId, affiliateId, details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use neither. I'd use a design that implements the same log method for each implementation. So it looks like Design #1, but a little different.

- abstract class Logger

  - log(string)

Create descendants for each type of log you have and override the log method.

Then, create a factory for specific purposes, so:

- class QueryLoggerFactory

  - getInstance() // Returns a/the FireBugConsoleLogger instance
- class ErrorLoggerFactory

  - getInstance() // Returns a database logger instance
- class HistoryLoggerFactory

  - getInstance() // Returns same or different database logger instance

That way, when you need to log a query, you just call

```
QueryLoggerFactory->getInstance()->log($query);
```

And nowhere in your application you need to call a specific method. If you decide you want to store the query in the database too, you just instantiate a different logger in your factory. You can even instantiate a logger that logs itself to two other loggers, so you can store errors in FireBug *and* in the database. Or you can instantiate a void logger that doesn't log anything.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking about this too much. Simple Strategy pattern should work well for this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Because the log() methods for database-related logging take different parameters, I think I'll have the QueryLogger class be its own top-level class, while ErrorLogger and HistoryLogger will inherit from the abstract Logger class.